# How does ThreadMXBean obtain thread CPU time and memory?

Tags: java, jvm

I follow the jdk documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html#isThreadCpuTimeEnabled--)
Knowing that we can obtain the CPU time and memory consumption of threads through ThreadMXBean, I want to know what technology is used to achieve these points at the bottom of the JVM? I want to know more about its internal underlying implementation

Comment: It may take a little exploring, but you should be able to follow the source code to see how it all works: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean, but the openjdk source code is too big and too big. On the one hand, I may have limited abilities and have not yet been able to read the openjdk source code to understand his entire implementation system; on the other hand, I mainly want to understand a core The principle, for example, is based on a certain mechanism of the operating system. I will focus on understanding that mechanism.

Comment: You already got it, it’s “based on a certain mechanism of the operating system”. Since every operating system is different and you didn’t name one, there is no more specific answer.

Comment: ok, I want to know how to achieve under Linux, in fact, I have found the answer：https://www.modb.pro/db/137619